# How can I read the URL entered in a browser's address bar?

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, web, server-side

My Java application used in blocking certain websites, when the application is running the websites that mentioned in it must be blocked. So, when anyone trying to reach a certain website from any browser I have to read the URL he trying to reach and compare it with the forbidden websites that stored in my application.

This is my problem, I can't connect the browsers that are in the system with my application. 
kind regards and sorry for that much talk :)

Comment: Java is not the right language for this.  Perhaps JS is (if you consider browser extensions).  You do realize that Java & Javascript are entirely separate languages, right?

Comment: This is almost impossible to perform client-side, unless you install an application on their computer which cannot be removed (e.g. a workplace).  Otherwise, the client can do whatever they like, including simply uninstalling Java (or whatever you're using for your application).  If you're looking to make a content filter service, attempting to stop users entering in URLs isn't really an effective countermeasure, as a client could simply use telnet, wget or something similar instead of using the browser.

Comment: Also to properly block a user in all scenarios you will have to do it on a server. there are ways to can identify the url in a server also.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;


HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```